# Specifying a Shebang path in a shell script

Tags: shell, path

I am running a VM with Ubuntu on it.

In a very simple script I wrote I defined the shebang as:

`#!/bin/zsh`

However, `zsh` also exists in `/usr/bin/zsh`.

Does it matter which path I use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I expect you'll find that `/usr/bin/zsh` is a symlink to `/bin/zsh`:

```
# ls -l /usr/bin/zsh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8 Apr 15 10:25 /usr/bin/zsh -> /bin/zsh
```

The shebang will work with a symlink, so it doesn't matter which path you use, as long as both exist in your system.

Comment: Yes, it said something like `zsh -> /bin/zsh`. So there is nothing wrong with having a symlink as a path, thanks for confirming